# insert all record into table1 from table2 using where like clause

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

Table1

```
ID - Metrics - t000
1 - chattervolume - BTC0908473
2 - negsent - NULL
```

Table2

```
ID - Metrics - t000
```

I want to insert Table1 data to Table2 using WHERE LIKE t000 '%BTC%' clause and If any column of field t000 not found anything in LIKE clause then it inserts N/A in column

Comment: Do you want both rows to be inserted? Or only the one with %BTC% ?

Comment: Do you try any insert statement yourself? Please share it with us as something to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all rows from `table1` to be inserted into `table2` (and only some modifications in column `t000`) then you can't use `WHERE`. You could use a `CASE` expression:

```
INSERT INTO table2
  ( ID, Metrics, t000 )
SELECT 
    ID, Metrics, CASE WHEN t000 LIKE '%BTC%' THEN t000 ELSE 'N/A' END
FROM
    table1 ;
```

---

If you want only rows that have `t000 LIKE '%BTC%'` or `t1000` is `NULL` then yes, you need a `WHERE` clause::

```
INSERT INTO table2
  ( ID, Metrics, t000 )
SELECT 
    ID, Metrics, COALESCE(t000, 'N/A')
FROM
    table1 
WHERE 
  ( t000 LIKE '%BTC%' OR t1000 IS NULL ) ;
```